# How to avoid errors on nonfound model in method with model class as parameter?

Tags: laravel

When in laravel 8 I define destroy method with model class as parameter

```
public function destroy(Ad $ad)
{
    $ad->delete();

    return [];
}
```

on request in POSTMAN with non existing Ad I got not only 404 error code, but also error messages :

```
"message": "No query results for model [App\\Models\\Ad] 6",
"exception": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException",
"file": "/project//vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php",
"line": 385,
"trace": [
    {
        "file": "/project//vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php",
        "line": 332,
        "function": "prepareException",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler",
        "type": "->"
    },
```

If there is a way to deal it not to get errors in          in POSTMAN output ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: The reason you're getting the extra error is because you have `APP_DEBUG` set to `true`.

Comment: Yes, can I catch it some why under dev mode ?

Comment: Are you wanting it to not return a 404 or not return the error message with the 404?

Comment: I want to  return  404 error without error  message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove the extra detail from the body of the response, you can simply set `APP_DEBUG=false`.

If you also want to remove the `message` as well you can do this in your `app/Exceptions/Handler.php class` by overriding the `render` method:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException; // <-- add to the top of the class

public function render($request, Throwable $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof ModelNotFoundException && $request->wantsJson()) {
        return response('steve', 404);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

Alternatively, if you also want to remove the `message` from the body for all `NotFoundHttpException`s, you could instead add the following to the `register` method:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException; // <-- add to the top of the class

$this->renderable(function (NotFoundHttpException $e, $request) {
    if ($request->wantsJson()) {
        return response('', 404);
    }
});
```

This will only change the result for JSON responses, the standard 404 page will still be used for non-JSON responses.

**NB** At the time of writing, you can't use the `renderable` method for intercepting a `ModelNotFoundException` as it gets converted to a `NotFoundHttpException` in the `prepareException` method before the `renderable` callbacks are executed.

---

Answer (score 1):

```
public function destroy(Ad $ad): array 
{
    try{ 
       $ad->delete();
    } catch(ModelNotFoundException $modelNotFoundException) {
       // do something here
    } 

    return [];
}
```

You could catch the ModelNotfoundException here.

Comment: That did not help. I got the same error, looks like before flow entered  destroy method

Comment: Or try to catch the `Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException`

Comment: Adding a `try/catch` here won't work as the exception will have already been thrown since the OP is using route model binding.